# Access any position in C++ empty string

Tags: c++, string

Why C++ empty string can be accessed at any position without error?

For example,

```
string str("");
```

`str[1]`, `str[2]` will just return empty.

Why doesn't the following statement throw error?

```
str[2] = 'a'
```

But, printing out `str` still show empty string.

I am confused here and probably miss something.

Comment: what compiler are you using? because mine explodes when i try to assign `std::string str("")` `str[2] = 'a'`

Comment: It could return empty, but it could also format your hard drive.

Comment: All you're missing is that this is _Undefined Behaviour_, that C++ doesn't protect you from _Undefined Behaviour_, and that it's generally better to avoid UB instead of trying to guess which particular unpredictable failure mechanism a given compiler will select.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing out-of-range subscript is undefined. For an empty `std::string`, using any subscript is illegal.

However, it's not required for the library to check the value of the subscript. The job of making sure the subscript is legal is left to the programmer, i.e, you.

Answer (score 3):

The string is (sort of) an array of characters you can stick stuff in.  When you make it "" it guarantees a length of **at least** 0 characters are available.  When you assign something to character [2] the behaviour is undefined and it is entitled to blow up, but there's a fair chance it will be large enough to absorb your mistake without noticing...

Comment: And a very good chance that if it does blow up, it will do so somewhere completely unexpected and apparently not connected to the string at all.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` elements can be accessed using the `[]` operator and using the `at()` function. The operator is required to perform no bounds checks, just like regular array access in C++, whereas the function throws `out_of_range` for invalid indices.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers by Yu and Andy, which are correct of course, I'd like to point you to `string::at` which, unlike `string::operator[]` would do bounds checking and through an exception if you attempt out-of-bounds access:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s("");
    return s.at(1);
}
```

The output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at
Aborted (core dumped)
```